# Really basic questions about the PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Suppose that I had a logged in user through the Facebook PHP SDK, and that I had permission to fetch the bio (user_about_me) and the education (user_education_history). If I wanted to fetch that data, how would I go about doing that? I know that if I wanna get the user interests, I just run

```
$facebook->api("/me/interests");
```

However, this does not work for the bio and education history. Using the PHP SDK, how can I get this data? Thanks.

**EDIT: Here's a picture of the app permissions, as well as the code used to request the permissions.**

[image: The Permissions for My App]

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email, publish_stream, 
user_about_me, user_interests, user_education_history'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `$facebook->api("/me/about") ;` OR `$facebook->api("/me/bio") ;` It will throw a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Unknown path components: /about thrown in 
[...]/base_facebook.php on line 1028
```

If you want to get user_about_me and user_education_history you can do it like:

```
$user = $facebook->api("/me") ;
```

Then parse the $user array to obtain the values you need . IF you wan use education history then you can do:

```
$user_education_history = $user['education'];
```

Hope this helps,. :)

Comment: That's weird, the $user array doesn't contain the bio or education. Is this where it always should be? Does /me/ return all data that the app has permission to get?

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler Please see my edit. You need to give permissions

Comment: I added a picture of the permissions to my post. Isn't it supposed to work this way?

Comment: This is fine. You should get things working. Anway include read_stream permissions too

Comment: Why is that? Also, when I request permission, why does the user first have to click "install", and then give me more permissions?

Comment: Its the facebook basic functionality. You need to click on install for application authentication

Comment: I somehow got it to work now, exactly as you told me to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As i remember $facebook->api('/me'); gets all information about user.

Comment: Not the bio or the education.

Comment: If you have the permissions granted it will, otherwise it excludes them.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this:

```
$facebook->api("/me") ;
```

You can get all user information from this . Just parse the array for what you required . It outputs all the user related information. You will get only that information which you are having permission to fetch.

Update:
Permissions required:

```
bio: user_about_me or friends_about_me
education:user_education_history or friends_education_history
```

If you want specific then use:

```
$facebook->api('/me?fields=bio,education');
```

Comment: I have tried this before. It only returns the user ID, not the desired information.

Comment: Is api("/me") prints only user id? It will give all data you have permissions. Do you have extended permission to access bio and education information?

Comment: Yes, when I go to my account settings and see the permissions given to the app, bio and education are among them.